# To change the IDENTITY property of a column, the column needs to be dropped and recreated

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, entity-framework-core

This was my initial model pushed to the database:

```
 public class OrderLine
 {
        [Key]
        public int OrderID { get; set; }
        public string Identifier { get; set; }

        public string Customer { get; set; }

        public OrderLine(string identifier)
        {
            Identifier = identifier;
        }

        public List<BasketEntryDto> Items { get; set; } = new List<BasketEntryDto>();
}
```

and

```
[Keyless]
[NotMapped]
public class BasketEntryDto
{
    public int ProductId { get; set; }
    public int Quantity { get; set; }
}
```

But then I realized that I wanted my `BasketEntryDto` to be like this:

```
public class BasketEntryDto
{
    [Key]
    public int ProductId { get; set; }
    public int Quantity { get; set; }
}
```

So that I could get that `BasketEntryDto` to save posted data to the database in a table. But when I do `Update-Database` after `Add-Migration`, I get this error:

> To change the IDENTITY property of a column, the column needs to be dropped and recreated.

This is my database `OrderLine`:

[image: DB]

I want my `BasketEntryDto` to be added to that `OrderLine` database so that when I POST data to it, it receives it and adds it to DB, am I doing something wrong here or is there a better way of doing this ? I want to store the following data when posting:

```
{
    "orderID": 6,
    "identifier": "mostNewestCustomerIn2025",
    "customer": " John Appleseed ",
    "items": [
        {
            "productId": 2021,
            "quantity": 1
        }
    ]
}
```

But I'm only getting this back in response (an empty array of "items":

```
{
        "orderID": 6,
        "identifier": "mostNewestCustomerIn2025",
        "customer": " John Appleseed ",
        "items": []
    }
```

I tried dropping the column manually in SQL Server Management Studio, but that didn't do anything.

Thanks in advance for any help

Comment: It's nearly true; you usually have to recreate the column (or table) to change the IDENTITYness of a column. If the table is empty, just get on and do it. If it's a live system with thousands fo things it's more tricky, but you can effectively create a new empty table that is the table you wish the current table was and then tell SQLS to swap the datastore between the two, so  the new table becomes the one full of data. You'll need to reseed/update the identity column post op so that it continues on (or seed it from a high enough number that the existing records won't collide)

Comment: @CaiusJard Hey man, thanks for taking your time to help, alright so I dropped the table and I'm going to try and re-add it to the database with Add-Migration, is that the way to do it? Didn't have much important data in it, just want it to work correctly

Comment: See what adding a migration gives you in terms of code - it might be confused because it won't necessarily have seen the table disappear (if you remove it from your client side, then run an add-mig it would see it's gone and generate the drop, then add it back and run another add-mig, so it sees it anew and generates the add.. you've effectively done manually the work it would have wanted to do..)

Comment: @CaiusJard Okay so If I understand it right then I have to Add-Migration twice before it understand that table is dropped? Thanks for helping me understand

Comment: Er, what i'm saying is give the migration a go and see what happens! :D It'll be possible to fix it whatever, but there might be some tweaking.. Some operations are difficult for EF to detect what happened and hence what should be done, but you'll find out by looking at the migration code it generates, what it thinks.. ANd if youre in the good place of this being a new project, just starting out and doesn't matter what stuck the migrations go into, it's easy to just chuck the context away and scaff it again from the DB (after you make the table in the DB to be how you want it)

Comment: @CaiusJard Hehe, alright then! Yeah well I did what I thought was easiest and dropped the table directly via SSMS then manually removed the migrations associated with that table in my solution, then I Cleaned Solution and Rebuild Solution and added a new migration the n updated database and it worked, now all that is left is to check if it gives me the result I want. Thanks for the help mate!

Comment: You can also manually manipulate the migration. EF migrations wont have a good solution on it's own, but you can manipulate the migration to create a new table with a temp name, copy the data across, drop the original table and rename the temp table, or any variation of that.

Comment: @ChrisSchaller Thanks Chris! Yeah it seems that manually manipulating it rather than depending on it makes things much easier, much appreciated for the help mate

Comment: Do your 2 other columns *really* need to contain up to ~1 billion/2GB of characters? `MAX` data types should only be used when you *really* need to store very large amounts of text. I would, personally, suggest that you could easily make a identifier that is significantly shorter than ~1 billion characters long and guarantee uniqueness for billions, or even trillions of rows.

Comment: @Larnu Not really, it did it automatically when I updated the database, I can change this directly though, right? In SQL SMS?

Comment: You can use the `[StringLength(20)]` attribute (20 is arbitrary) to specify the max length of the column in SQL. Without specifying a length, the model is unconstrained, so Max is expected. You can implement your own conventions to limit types but `StringLengthAttribute` is the right place to start.

Comment: Forgetting that this is an EF migration and putting on my DBA hat, you needn't drop/recreate a table to change the identity property of a column. You can create a new (empty) table that matches the definition of the current table in all but the identity property of that column and do a partition switch of the old table to the new one.